# How to resize picture in PHP?

Tags: php, image, resize

Below is my code to upload pictures in a folder in PHP.

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
    $id= $_GET['id'];

    $folder = 'uploads/';
    $filename = $id.'.jpg';


    $uploaddir = './uploads/';

     // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
     // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
     if ( !file_exists($folder) ) {
        mkdir ($folder, 0744);
     }

    $data = $_POST['base64data'];

    $type = '';

    list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
    list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
    $data = base64_decode($data);

    $file_path = $folder.$filename;

    echo $_POST['base64data'];

    file_put_contents($file_path, $data);
}
```

But, how to resize the uploaded pictures to a size i want ?

I found a PHP function but I am not sure how to implement it in my code... This is `imagecopyresampled`:

```
// Le fichier
$filename = 'test.jpg';

// Définition de la largeur et de la hauteur maximale
$width = 200;
$height = 200;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Cacul des nouvelles dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Redimensionnement
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Affichage
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to do this :

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
    /*put the code which resize your image here*/
        $id= $_GET['id'];

        $folder = 'uploads/';
        $filename = $id.'.jpg';


        $uploaddir = './uploads/';

         // create new directory with 744 permissions if it does not exist yet
         // owner will be the user/group the PHP script is run under
         if ( !file_exists($folder) ) {
            mkdir ($folder, 0744);
         }

        $data = $_POST['base64data'];

        $type = '';

        list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
        list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
        $data = base64_decode($data);

        $file_path = $folder.$filename;

        echo $_POST['base64data'];

        file_put_contents($file_path, $data);
    }
```

and in the commentary after you use imagecopyresampled to resize your image (try it with an image in local) you have to get the content type and after follow the rest of the script of imagecopyresampled.

or you can do it : check it out :

[nimrodstech.com/php-image-resize](http://nimrodstech.com/php-image-resize)

[github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize](http://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize)

Comment: Do you have an exemple? I'm not sure to see what you mean.

Comment: or you can do it : 

check it out :

http://www.nimrodstech.com/php-image-resize/

https://github.com/Nimrod007/PHP_image_resize

Comment: Thanks for help!! :-D Everything is with your links!

Comment: no problem :) vote up my answer in order to help other person

Answer (score 0):

```
   **Resize images with PHP**


 <?php

     if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {
        echo "Error: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "<br />";
    } else {
        // array of valid extensions
        $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
        // get extension of the uploaded file
        $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], ".");
        // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
        if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
            $newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
            $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
            // resizing to 200x200
            $newImage = $manipulator->resample(200, 200);
            // saving file to uploads folder
            $manipulator->save('uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
            echo 'Done ...';
        } else {
            echo 'You must upload an image...';
        }
    }

**Crop  images with PHP**

if ($_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['error'] . "<br />";
} else {
    // array of valid extensions
    $validExtensions = array('.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.png');
    // get extension of the uploaded file
    $fileExtension = strrchr($_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'], ".");
    // check if file Extension is on the list of allowed ones
    if (in_array($fileExtension, $validExtensions)) {
        $newNamePrefix = time() . '_';
        $manipulator = new ImageManipulator($_FILES['fileToUpload']['tmp_name']);
        $width  = $manipulator->getWidth();
        $height = $manipulator->getHeight();
        $centreX = round($width / 2);
        $centreY = round($height / 2);
        // our dimensions will be 200x130
        $x1 = $centreX - 100; // 200 / 2
        $y1 = $centreY - 65; // 130 / 2

        $x2 = $centreX + 100; // 200 / 2
        $y2 = $centreY + 65; // 130 / 2

        // center cropping to 200x130
        $newImage = $manipulator->crop($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2);
        // saving file to uploads folder
        $manipulator->save('uploads/' . $newNamePrefix . $_FILES['fileToUpload']['name']);
        echo 'Done ...';
    } else {
        echo 'You must upload an image...';
    }
}
```